# Custom Toolbar overlapping Fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, toolbar

So basically i'm trying to set a fragment up so that it shows my badges and for some reason it just won't fit the screen and starts from the top. It seems this results in the toolbar floating over the whole fragment. Is there something i'm doing wrong that anyone can point out? I'm using three fragments with a tabbing system.

[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VO7fy.jpg)

1) Fragment (myFragment.java)

```
public class myFragment extends Fragment {


public myFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private badgeAdapter adapter;
private List<hatBadge> badge;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_closet, container, false);
    final FragmentActivity c = getActivity();
    final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    badge = new ArrayList<>();

    adapter = new badgeAdapter(getContext(), badge);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new myFragment.GridSpacingItemDecoration(2, dpToPx(10), true));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            c.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
            });
        }
    }).start();

    prepareAlbums();

    return view;
}
/**
 * Adding few albums for testing
 */
private void prepareAlbums() {
    int[] covers = new int[]{
            R.drawable.nike,
            R.drawable.nike,
            R.drawable.nike,
            R.drawable.nike};

    hatBadge a = new hatBadge("Hat 1", 13, covers[0]);
    badge.add(a);

    a = new hatBadge("Hat 1", 8, covers[1]);
    badge.add(a);

    a = new hatBadge("Hat 5", 11, covers[2]);
    badge.add(a);

    a = new hatBadge("Hat 5", 11, covers[2]);
    badge.add(a);


    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

/**
 * RecyclerView item decoration - give equal margin around grid item
 */
public class GridSpacingItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private int spanCount;
    private int spacing;
    private boolean includeEdge;

    public GridSpacingItemDecoration(int spanCount, int spacing, boolean includeEdge) {
        this.spanCount = spanCount;
        this.spacing = spacing;
        this.includeEdge = includeEdge;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view); // item position
        int column = position % spanCount; // item column

        if (includeEdge) {
            outRect.left = spacing - column * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
            outRect.right = (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // (column + 1) * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)

            if (position < spanCount) { // top edge
                outRect.top = spacing;
            }
            outRect.bottom = spacing; // item bottom
        } else {
            outRect.left = column * spacing / spanCount; // column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
            outRect.right = spacing - (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - (column + 1) * ((1f /    spanCount) * spacing)
            if (position >= spanCount) {
                outRect.top = spacing; // item top
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Converting dp to pixel
 */
private int dpToPx(int dp) {
    Resources r = getResources();
    return Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, r.getDisplayMetrics()));
}

}
```

2) Activity running Fragment (myActivity.java)

```
public class myActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Toolbar toolbar;
TabLayout tabLayout;
ViewPager viewPager;
ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Remove title bar
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab);

    toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new homeFragment(), "Info");
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new myFragment(), "my Fragment");
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new careFragment(), "Care");
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

}
```

3) fragment_my_closet.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/viewBg"
>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:clipToPadding="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

4) Activity_tab.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >
        <include
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
            />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            ></android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        ></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>
```

5) toolbar_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"

android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:id="@+id/toolBar"
app:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Can you add the screenshot to the post?

Comment: I have added the screenshot, it happens with all my 3 fragments they start from the top of the screen instead of just right under the toolbar as a starting point.

Comment: That `new Thread` is really not necessary, by the way

Answer (score 1):

[AppBarLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html) depends on being a child of a `CoordinatorLayout`. It also needs a scrolling view that implements a `ScrollingViewBehavior`. There's a standard one implemented for you that can be used by setting `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >
        <include
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
            />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: problem was <RelativeLayout> in Activity_tab.xml. Needs to be changed to LinearLayout